# Using siunitx package with Optics Express journal template

Tags: errors, siunitx

Drafting a manuscript for Optics Express, using a template provided by the Optical Society of America, I stumbled on following incompatibility with the package siunitx. Namely,

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{opex3}
\usepackage{siunitx}
...
```

results in an error line 69 saying: `! Package siunitx Error: Unit \as already defined!.`, even though the original text file did not have LaTeX input on line 69. Apparently, entering the packages in a different order gets rid of the error message:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{opex3}
...
```

So, as far as I understand there must be a duplicate definition of the `\as` (attosecond) command. Why is the error message indicating an error on line 69, while the error seems to happen at the preamble of the document? But also, why does the error not occur when the package definition is swapped around?

(Using pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10, on Ubuntu 12.04 with Texmaker)

Comment: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/osa/optics_express

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example showing the problem? When i test `\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{opex3}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
test
\si{\as}
\end{document}
` it works great.

Comment: Your minimal example does not work for me, resulting in the error reported above. When I change the order of the packages, it works.

Comment: The file `opex3.sty` does *not* appear to define a macro called `\as`.

Comment: Which TeX distribution (i.e., which vintage of TeXLive) and which version of `siunitx` do you use? This information should be contained in the log file.

Comment: One can start by asking why are they distributing a version of `keyval` and `geometry` along with their own style file? Especially when those copies are 10+ years old!

Comment: And like the others I have no problem adding `siunitx` to the template provided by the Society. Using an up to date TeX Live 204.

Comment: @Mico, sorry, but I am not that proficient: how do I find out the exact version of `siunitx` and TeXLive? I have a normal up to date 12.04 Ubuntu distro.

Comment: @Mico But one does get defined: try it :-) (Its on line 254 of the version I got from the journal website.)

Comment: @PieterDeBeule To see the version of package(s) in use, add `\listfiles` to your input and look in the `.log` file for a `File list`. Here that's not required: I can be certain of which version is in use (you'd expect so as I'm the package author!).

Comment: @JosephWright - I was using the version of `apex3.sty` that's on the CTAN.

Comment: @Mico That's another issue: the two files claim the same version but they are not identical! (The one from the journal website is 290 lines, the CTAN one 275 lines.)

Comment: @JosephWright - Yikes! Yet another sign that the `opex3` package shouldn't be loaded lightly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With older versions of `siunitx` the standard settings attempted to create abbreviation units macros in such a way that existing definitions caused problems. With `opex3` the provided defintion of `\as` is a shortcut for  `Appl.\ Spectrosc.\`  which is where the issue comes. (Yes, there is a space at the end of that shortcut: not a great plan!)

The reason the error only happens with one load order and gives a 'funny' line reference is due to the way the unit is created. In version 1 of `siunitx` there is in a file `si-abbr.cfg` which has on line 69 the definition

```
\newunit{\as}{\atto\second}
```

When you load `opex3` first, the `\newunit` command checks for an existing `\as`, finds one issues an error. On the other hand, if you load `siunitx` first then there is no definition of `\as` so `siunitx` just creates one. The code in `opex3` does no checking and so overwrites the `siunitx` one.

The best 'fix' depends on your requirements:

- Just load `siunitx` first as you've already found: this will overwrite `\as` with the `opex3` version
- Turn off loading of the abbreviation file with `\usepackage[noload=abbr]{siunitx}`
- Remove the definition that `opex` gives for `\as`

  ```
  \usepackage{opex3}
  \let\as\relax
  ```
- Install v2 of `siunitx` from CTAN (needs `l3packages` and `l3kernel`): this is the best 'long term' solution but probably the most tricky, so if your only requirement is the one outlined in the question perhaps don't go this way!

Comment: Not directly part of the answer, but the file `opex3.sty` is quite frankly awful: out of date, bad definitions, _etc._ I would strongly suggest not using it but instead using a 'vanilla' `article` file and adding only what you absolutely require.

Comment: The journal website states: Use the additional substyle, opex3.sty; a separate custom style file should be used only if absolutely necessary. I am not really proficient enough in LaTeX to start deviating from this.

Comment: @PieterDeBeule One to raise with the journal editorial office: ultimately their call.

Comment: I informed the editorial office regarding this. Let's wait and see.